# Python settings in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext2

When I press `ctrl+B` in SB2 in the console I get `ImportError: No module named site`.
How to fix it?

Comment: what is the code you are trying to build?

Comment: No matter what I'm trying to build. Even `print 'Hello World'` causes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you saved the file with `.py` extension and then try to run again. You also need to check that the Python in your .sublime-build is correct. For this look at `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Python\Python.sublime-build` file. This file should have something like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

This is equivalent to doing the following on the command line, check that you can do:

```
python -u C:\your_path\your_script.py
```

If this doesn't work from the command line it also wont from sublime.